# Cookies not Saving Offline

Tags: java, session, url, cookies, server

I'm trying to create an app that pings a server, receives a session id (if the username and password are correct), then creates a cookie with that session ID and downloads the data from that website by logging in with that cookie. Unfortunately, I'm getting an output from the website that is blank, meaning that the cookie didn't save offline for some reason and the application was unable to logon to the website. Why is the cookie not saving offline?

Here is the code, for reference:

```
package main;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import org.apache.http.cookie.Cookie;

public class Example {

public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, Exception {
    //Authentication
    String account = "fedorparetsky@yahoo.com"; //fill your account info
    String password = "fedorp00"; //fill your password info
    String sessionId = getData(account, password);
    if(sessionId.equals("-1")) {
        System.out.println("Invalid user credentials");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    try {
        URL url = new URL("https://api.ragic.com/parcare/new-tab/1");
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty("sessionId", sessionId);
        conn.connect();
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8"))) {
            for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (RuntimeException allDownloadExceptions) {
        allDownloadExceptions.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static String getData(String email, String password) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL("https://api.ragic.com/AUTH?" + "u=" + email + "&p=" + password + "&login_type=sessionId");
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8"))) {
        for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
            return line;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Just so you know, I am a beginner at Java and new on this forum. Thanks for the help!

Comment: what is the purpose of this `for` loop - `for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
            return line;
        }` ?

Comment: sorry, I meant to delete that earlier but copied the wrong version of the code. It's meant to just return the first line from the URL.

Comment: also, I don't see your `Cookie` `import` getting used anywhere in pasted code? Point out from pasted code as which line is not working as per your expectation. Your issue is not clear from description.If you have pasted incorrect code, you can always edit your question.